# Is there way to get emoji id by emoji string in discord.py?

Tags: discord.py

I trying to get emoji id by emoji string. Emoji string is looks like this:<:emojiname:emojiid>

Comment: If you have the emoji object you can just use `emoji.id`. https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html?highlight=emoji#discord.Emoji Otherwise see the answer by Ratery below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```py
s = "<:emojiname:emojiid>"
print(s.split(":", 2)[-1][:-1])
```

Or use a regex.

Comment: Use a regex is working! emoji_ id = re.findall(r"\d+", emoji); bot.get_emoji(int(emoji_id[-1]))